# Building importing/linking a Derelict3 project using dub in D2

Tags: static-linking, d, derelict3

I am trying to build a D2/Derelict3 example:

```
import std.stdio;
import derelict.opengl3.gl3;
import derelict.glfw3.glfw3;

void main(string[] args)
{
    DerelictGL3.load();
    DerelictGLFW3.load();


if (!glfwInit()) throw new Exception("Failed to initialize GLFW");

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "Hello DerelictGLFW3", null, null);
    if (!window) throw new Exception("Window failed to create");

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
}
```

but I get the following error:

```
app.d(0,0): Error: module gl is in file 'derelict\opengl3\gl.d' which cannot be read (d2derelict)
```

I have built Derelict3 using the guide on the Derelict github page, and init'ed a folder with dub.

How do I configure dub to include the libraries in my project?